# SQL DATE extraction from a column

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Schedult table]
I have a table 'schedule' and column 'travel_date'.
travel_date is having 'a predefined date' in that.

I want to alter that column with '5days' more.

like

```
UPDATE Schedule SET travel_date=''+5days ;
```

I used 
    UPDATE schedule SET travel_date = (travel_date+5);
It worked how ?

Comment: Is `register_date` a string or an actual `datetime`-related column?

Comment: datetime column

Comment: Hint:  `register_date + interval 5 day`.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL you can do that with

```
UPDATE  customer
SET     register_date = DATE_ADD(register_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: I used - 
    UPDATE customer SET register_date=(register_date+5);
It worked. Please tell me how it worked?

Comment: I assume when adding a number to a date, MySQL givest to that number the meaning of days. Good to know if it works, but I think the answers you got make your query easier to understand, and they're also adaptable to other variations (adding minutes, months and so on)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to add 5 days to **every customers** register date???

Are you sure this is what you want to do?

```
UPDATE customer SET [register_date] = DATE_ADD([register_date], INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: getting this error 

SET TRAVEL_DATE = DATE_ADD(TRAVEL_DATE, INTERVAL 5 DAY)   
ERROR at line 2:                                                                
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @ShyamSundar Edit your post to contain the whole query you are running... the snippet you posted will not generate that error...

Answer (score 0):

If it is a datetime column, use the [`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp) function:

`UPDATE customer SET register_date = DATE_ADD(register_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)`

Answer (score 0):

**Using `DATE_ADD()`**

You can use the [`DATE_ADD()`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/date_add.php) function to handle adding a given interval (e.g. days, minutes, hours, etc.) to an existing date column:

```
UPDATE customer
   SET register_date = DATE_ADD(register_date, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

**Using Date Arithmetic**

Alternatively, you can simply use date arithmetic as well, which is similar to your previous example:

```
UPDATE customer
   SET register_date = register_date + INTERVAL 5 DAY
```